# Firefox returns TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null but Chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've seen a lot of questions about this and I think I scanned through almost all of them but haven't found a solution for my problem yet.

As I mention in the title, Firefox (and IE) return this exception `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` while Chrome and Safari work just fine.

I have the code online which you can check out here: http://178.62.244.224/ (the site's in Portuguese but that's not relevant for this issue).

The problem: when clicking on one of the refinements on the left side, Chrome behaves as expected and toggles the checkbox while loading new content through Ajax. When doing it in Firefox, the checkbox doesn't toggle (but the ajax call works because content changes) and the aforementioned exception shows up in the console.

The code it points to is in `script.js` (http://178.62.244.224/static/script.js) in this function in the getElementById line:

```
function toggleAllFilters(filters) {
    for (i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
        var filter = filters[i];
        document.getElementById(filter).checked = true;
    }
};
```

This function is called in `getFilters()` in an ajax call:

```
$.get(url, function (response) {
            document.open();
            document.write(response);
            document.close();
            toggleAllFilters(filters);
        });
```

As pointed in other similar questions, this seems to have to do with the fact that when doing `document.getElementById` the page might not be fully loaded yet and the element isn't found. For that reason I already moved `script.js` to the end of the page right before `</body>` but this had no effect.

It's clear that Firefox/IE interpret this in a different way but I really can't find out in what way. Any ideas?

Comment: that was my first thougt too, but filters is just the params of the function which is called by line 44 whichs is totally weired.

@bergonzzi : Please please please use jQuery. jQuery is made for exactly what you are doing. everything is working with ease, and no more problems with getElementById

Comment: @huanson it's not really my code, I'm just adapting it but I'm a beginner in javascript. You're probably right, any tips about how to improve this are appreciated.

Comment: with jQuery looks something like that. non tested, just edited. http://pastie.org/10332858

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the selector in quotes.

```
getElementById('filter')
```

What you have above is looking for a variable pointer, not an actual DOM element.

Comment: I don't think so... filter is a variable, and 'filter' just make it a id string.

Comment: Indeed, that doesn't work, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null` and the same on Firefox if I do that, as @iplus26 mentioned `filter` becomes a string.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that, but yes. Totally wrong. You are *indeed* sending the query a pointer. Apologies for distracting you with useless information. I wonder if this may be a scope issue?